# NUnit Assert.IsInstanceOf<T> - no way to ensure not a derived class?

Tags: c#, nunit

I have two classes: Foo and FooBar. FooBar derives from Foo.  I have a factory class that, given parameters, decides which object to instantiate and return.

So I want to have unit tests that verify my factory class is working properly and returning the proper instances.

This is somewhat clean for FooBar:

```
[Test]
public void FooBarFactoryTest()
{
    var testObj = FooFactory(paramsForFooBarOnly);
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<FooBar>(testObj);
}
```

But for Foo, it's rather messy:

```
[Test]
public void FooFactoryTest()
{
    var testObj = FooFactory(paramsForFooOnly);
    Assert.IsInstanceOf<Foo>(testObj);  //An instance of FooBar would pass this assert
    Assert.IsNotInstanceOf<FooBar>(testObj);  //Can't have just this assert.
}
```

Is there any way I can re-write this second test to follow the paradigm of "One assert per test?"  Preferably, I'd also like to have tests that account for potential additional derivations of Foo or FooBar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, just use `Assert.IsTrue`:

```
Assert.IsTrue(testObj.GetType() == typeof(Foo));
```

Don't feel like you have to choose only from the various "helper" methods from NUnit.

Comment: I think your comment is rather profound; I was so hung up on finding "the right helper," the simple and easy answer didn't occur to me.

Comment: @Peter I think there is generally too much emphasis put on assert choices in the automation community. Did you report the proper result? Did you provide the information necessary to start debugging in the case of failure? If the answer to both those questions is yes then I'm pretty indifferent about which assert you use.